# Making an unknown class instance

Tags: c++, class, reference

This sounds simple, but right now I am utterly confused. How can I prevent an instance of a class to go out of scope without including the class definition in my header file? Can I use some kind of forward reference. I use C++ VS2017. I hope that the following pseudo-code makes my intention clear.

```
// MyHeader.h
class X
{
    class ThirdPartyClass &tpc;  // This must require a forward definition
    // and many other things
}

// My program
#include "MyHeader.h"
int main ()
{
    X x;
    foo(x);
}

// A separately compiled module
#include "MyHeader.h"
#include "ThirdPartyClass.hpp" // (Very large)
void foo (class X &x)
{
    ThirdPartyClass localtpc;
    x.tpc = &localtpc;
}
```

I know it won't win a trophy for best code. What I want to do is keeping the instance of localtpc in memory after foo() exits.  ThirdPartyClass.hpp is enormous and I don't want to include ThirdPartyClass.hpp in my MyHeader.h.  Using a void * to hold a reference does not work, the instance of localtpc gets destructed. ThirdPartyClass maintains a reference count, but it cannot be explicitly manipulated. 
Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
HJB

Comment: Allocate `ThirdPartyClass` object with dynamic storage duration then. That is `auto p_obj{::std::make_unique<ThirdPartyClass>()};` and move it to `tpc` (which should be a smart pointer as well)

Comment: Do you have a .cpp file for your X class? If so, how do you intend to use `tpc` member without including the class definition and if you don't use `tpc` in your X class why is it a member of that class at all?

Comment: @VTT Answers go in the answer section buddy

Comment: @r3mus. The class X is the thing that must hold the reference to the TPC instance.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to note here is that since you've defined `tpc` as a reference, it must be initialized (not just assigned to), so something even on the general order of `x.tpc = &localtpc;` just won't work.

As to what will work, I can see (at least) two obvious possibilities. One creates a single instance of ThirdPartyClass, and then initializes all the `X` objects to contain pointers to that single instance:

```
// X.h
class X { 
    ThirdPartyClass &x;
public:
    X();
};

// X.cpp
#include "ThirdPartyClass.hpp"

X::X()
    : x(holder())
{}

ThirdPartyClass &holder() { 
    static ThirdPartyClass foo;
    return foo;
}
```

The other obvious possibility would be to use `new` to create an instance, and initialize your reference from there:

```
// X.h
class X { 
    ThirdPartyClass &x;
public:
    X();
};

// X.cpp
#include "ThirdPartyClass.hpp"

X::X()
    : x(* new ThirdPartyClass)
{}
```

As to which is preferred: it really depends on how you're using things. If you expect all instances of `x` to share a single instance of `ThirdPartyClass`, so (for example) a modification via one should be reflected in all the others, then you almost certainly want something at least vaguely similar to the former.

On the other hand, if each instance of `x` is expected to have a unique instance of `ThirdPartyClass`, then you almost certainly want something more like the latter.

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I found your solution to be the easiest to implement.  There are several instances of the ThirdPartyClass, so I use a simple new() and avoid the local instance.  In class X I use a void* to pre-define the pointer.

Comment: @DuxburyDutch: One other point though: as a general rule, if you're going to use `new`, you're probably better off using some sort of smart pointer class to automate freeing the pointer when the owning object is destroyed.